# Help determine the group of units of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt{m})/2]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

let $m$ be an integer with $m\equiv 1 \pmod4$ and $m<-3$.

$U\left(\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}(\frac{1+\sqrt{m}}{2})\right)=\{\pm1\}$
 How can I prove that?

Comment: Hint: If you already have proved some of the properties of **norm**, this should not be difficult.

Comment: To expand on Andre's comment. If $X = (1+\sqrt{m})/2$, then define $N(a+bX)=(a+bX)(a-bX)$. Notice that $N(AB)=N(A)N(B)$ (the norm is multiplicative). Also, $N(1)=1$. If $AB=1$, what can you say about $N(A),N(B)$?

Comment: @BillCook $(a+bX)(a-bX)$ is not the norm.  $(a+bX)(a+b\bar X)$ is the norm.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oops! Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 3):

If you've been introduced to enough machinery of Algebraic Number Theory, you can recognize:

- $\mathbb{Z}[(1 + \sqrt{m})/2]$ is the ring of integers in the number field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})$, and so...
- the free part of the unit group is trivial, by [Dirichlet's Unit Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_unit_theorem)

So it boils down to looking for roots of unity. However:

- $[ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{4}) : \mathbb{Q} ] = 2$
- $[ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{2^e}) : \mathbb{Q} ] \geq 4$ for $e \geq 3$
- $[ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{3}) : \mathbb{Q} ] = 2$
- $[ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{3^e}) : \mathbb{Q} ] \geq 6$ for $e \geq 2$
- $[ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^e}) : \mathbb{Q} ] \geq p-1$ for $p \geq 3$

Since $[ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{m}) : \mathbb{Q} ] = 2$, you just have to check that neither of $\sqrt{-1}$ and $\sqrt{-3}$ are in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})$.

In particular, you probably meant to assume $m$ is squarefree, since $\sqrt{-3} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-27})$ (and thus so is $\zeta_3$).

Comment: This is a side comment really, but how did you compute did the degree of those field extensions so quickly?

Comment: @Benjamin: I'm sure that people who do this stuff for a living have those degrees (or the calculation procedure) memorized. For me, really, the only thing I needed for this answer is that, for an odd prime, the roots of $x^p-1$ are $1$ and the $p-1$ primitive $p$-th roots of unity (which are all conjugate), and so $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p) : \mathbb{Q}] = p-1$. The $\zeta_8$ I did from memory (it helps to actually know the complex $8$-th roots of unity). I'm a little iffy on getting $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_9) : \mathbb{Q}]$ right, but all I *really* needed is that it's bigger than $2$.